# What are the characters in this image and what do they mean?

Tags: translation

What are the characters in this picture and what do they mean? I know the first one is 来    but I don't recognize the second one or know the meaning of these together. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyNja.jpg)

Comment: it means 'come on please'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 来唷
>
> Come on

来 means come.

唷 is a modal word that expresses the excited emotion of the speaker.